# A Drop Down List with Multiple Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

Is there a way to make a drop down list have multiple selects?  Holding CTRL. Maybe with a JQuery Plugin?

Comment: What do you want to show when somebody selecte multiple entires and collapses the list?

Comment: @nfechner there exists certain point in such control. Suppose you have 100 items. Dropdown with multiselect would display selected item captions in line and you would see all of them (if you selected just a couple of items). With regular listbox you don't know what's selected until you scroll all of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkout [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) if you have lots of elements, as this can be an issue with a standard select. it is highly customizable, from the website :

> Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes
>   much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and
>   Prototype flavors.

Not sure about the keyboard input though (which may not matter depending on your use case).

Comment: If its goal is to make a select box more user-friendly, it can't possibly be that it supports multi select dropdowns.

Comment: @GolezTrol : it does support multi-select in a friendlier way. Second example in the project page (it's a before-after presentation though, it can get confusing). Unless I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify [multiple="multiple"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) in your `select` element.

But remember. From a usability point of view, this isn't a very good solution. Maybe you should opt for a list of checkboxes instead.

Comment: This doesn't look like a drop down, does it?

Comment: @pimvdb Yeah, I know. But it's the first hit. And it explains things in such a way that even those who can't google will understand. ;-)

Comment: @Eugene Indeed it doesn't. It's just an advise to choose a different solution. Multi-select dropdowns suck. They're not usable at all. Avoid them.

Comment: i want it to look like a regular drop down list, not a box with a scroll bar so multiple DOES NOT work

Answer (score 0):

For one dropdown list you can set the "multiple" attribute.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp